# VS code error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointers and integers [-fpermissive]"

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, comparison, iso

I didn't even use pointers in my following code, but my compiler throwing an error calling it comparison between pointers and integers on VS code! How could I solve the issues?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    std::string sounds{0};
    std::getline (std::cin , sounds);
    int len {sounds.length()};
    std::string temp{0};

    for(int i=0; i<=len; i++){

        while (sounds[i] != " ")
        {
            temp += sounds[i];
        }
        
        if(temp == "Grr"){
            std::cout << "Lion" << " ";
        }else if(temp == "Rawr"){
            std::cout << "Tiger" << " ";
        }else if(temp == "Ssss"){
            std::cout << "Snake" << " ";
        }else if(temp == "Chirp"){
            std::cout << "Bird" << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sounds[i] != " "` is a comparison between a character and a pointer. The pointer being `const char*` for the string literal `" "`. You used the wrong quotation marks. Should have been `' '` instead of  `" "`

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=len; i++){` is an off by 1 error.

Comment: `std::string temp{0};` I believe will cause Undefined Behavior because the 0 I believe will be a null pointer. Use `std::string temp;` instead.

Comment: It still doesn't work!

Comment: The (corrected) while-loop `while (sounds[i] != ' ')` is potentially endless, as neither `i`  nor `sounds` are modified by the loop.  So the loop will either never start, or never end.  Well, actually it will end when you finally exceed available storage for the string `temp` at which time the program will throw an exception and then abort.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read a bunch of words sepated by whitespace from a line of input, but you are going about it in a very unusual way.  There are so many problems and potential problems that I think you should just delete everything from the beginning of `for` up until the first `if`, and replace it with: `for(std::istringstream iss(sounds); iss >> temp; ) {`.  Then include `<sstream>` in your program and Bob's your proverbial uncle.

Comment: Quote of compiler message would be very helpful.